# Stop event in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I used the example of this website : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/feature-animation.html for make an animation.

I don't have problem for stopping the event with the function `clearInterval(interval);` if I declare before my interval `var interval = window.setInterval(addRandomFeature,1000);`

The problem is I want to clear the layer who contain the object (after my function `clearInterval(interval);`) and I don't understand what's the layer who contain the event and I don't know how can I clear this layer.

Answer (score 0):

the only layer in the script has the name vector.

To clear the objects/featurees of this layer use:

```
vector.getSource().clear()
```